# Active Directory and PowerShell Does not Read a Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a script, but when I put the root manual, it will function perfectly but when I assign to a dinamical variable like I've commented `"$Usuario = dsquery user -d $Dominio -samid $User"` does not function and I receive an error:

> Get-ADUser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following
>    partition(s): At line:1 char:19 ,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$User        = "ET308990"
$Fecha       = Get-Date -format dd/MM/yyyy 
$Dominio     = "contoso"
$Descri      = " - Salida: "+$Fecha
$Usuario     = "CN=Folder4,OU=Folder3,OU=Folder2,OU=Folder1,DC=contoso,DC=com"
#    $Usuario     = dsquery user -d $Dominio -samid $User    
    Get-ADUser -server $Dominio -Filter * -SearchBase $Usuario -Properties Department,Description,DistinguishedName|
        foreach { Set-ADUser $_ -Description ($_.Description+$Descri)}
```

So I don't know Why don't read the dinamical variable, I'm so close.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing double quotes to the parameter `-SearchBase` and it is only expecting a string without quotes around it. I.e this is what the parameter is seeing from the variable `$Usuario`; extra set of quotation marks:

```
'"CN=Folder4,OU=Folder3,OU=Folder2,OU=Folder1,DC=contoso,DC=com"'
```

To remove these simply use the following `-replace` operation:

```
$Usuario = (dsquery user -d $Dominio -samid $User) -replace '"',''
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work perfectly Richard. I thought it need it quotes around it.